# how to convert a parameter list into a string in python without using the join function

Tags: list

I need to write a function which gets one parameter as a list with multipul values. the list needs to be converted into a string without using the join function.

I'd love to use some help!

thanks a lot

Comment: What have you already tried? This is too broad of a question as is.

Comment: In which language?. Try to write some codes that u have tried.

Comment: The language is Python. I'm pretty new at this so I don't have too many tools. basiclly I started by defining a function: concat_list(str_list). the str_list- should be getting a list when i'll call the function. I know that if I have 2 strings I can put a + in the middle and create one string but the "str_list  list can have lots and lots of strings in it [devided bt commas] so I'm not sure what I should do. i guess i should be using a loop? but dont know how to make it done ....